# How to scroll to top of element with collapsible panels with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

I have a series of divs that on click, toggle the state of a collapsible div (like an accordion widget). That is working fine, but I want to be able to scroll to the top of the trigger div (the div with class name 'panelTab') when the user clicks. The problem is that when the panels are hidden, they take up no space so jQuery doesn't automatically 'know' the size of the page, and isn't able to calculate to the top of the element automatically. So what happens is that on click it scrolls, but it 'overshoots' the top of the window and lands in the middle of the paragraph content. I'm stuck - anyone know a simple solution? Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="panelTab first holder">
<div class="text-block"> <h3>LOREM IPSUM</h3><p class="sub-title">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p> </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div> </div>
 <div class="animatedPanel"> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  adipiscing elit. Fusce ornare ornare lectus in pulvinar. Donec tempor odio sit amet phare- tra commodo. Suspendisse sem libero, tempor vitae egestas eu, sagittis sit amet metus. Sed congue tristique quam in gravida. Sed cursus, lectus vel rhoncus bibendum, erat ante mattis mauris, ac pharetra erat mauris nec turpis. Sed tincidunt aliquam est eget rhoncus. Proin eget metus ex. Sed sit amet eros feugiat, dignissim purus eget, rhoncus augue. Vestibulum lacinia tellus vel turpis vestibulum pharetra. Lestie, viverra mauris nec, semper turpis. Nunc accumsan augue ut ligula iaculis auctor.    </p></div>



<div class="panelTab holder">
<div class="text-block" > <h3>LOREM IPSUM </h3><p class="sub- title">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p> </div>

<div class="clearfix"></div></div>
<div class="animatedPanel"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ornare ornare lectus in pulvinar. Donec tempor odio sit amet phare- tra commodo. Suspendisse sem libero, tempor vitae egestas eu, sagittis sit amet metus. Sed congue tristique quam in gravida. Sed cursus, lectus vel rhoncus bibendum, erat ante mattis mauris, ac pharetra erat mauris nec turpis. Sed tincidunt aliquam est eget rhoncus. Proin eget metus ex. Sed sit amet eros feugiat, dignissim purus eget, rhoncus augue. Vestibulum lacinia tellus vel turpis vestibulum pharetra. Lestie, viverra mauris nec, semper turpis. Nunc accumsan augue ut ligula iaculis auctor. </p></div>

<div class="panelTab holder"><div class="text-block" > <h3>LOREM IPSUM</h3><p class="sub-title">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p> </div><div class="clearfix"></div></div>
<div class="animatedPanel"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ornare ornare lectus in pulvinar. Donec tempor odio sit amet phare- tra commodo. Suspendisse sem libero, tempor vitae egestas eu, sagittis sit amet metus. Sed congue tristique quam in gravida. Sed cursus, lectus vel rhoncus bibendum, erat ante mattis mauris, ac pharetra erat mauris nec turpis. Sed tincidunt aliquam est eget rhoncus. Proin eget metus ex. Sed sit amet eros feugiat, dignissim purus eget, rhoncus augue. Vestibulum lacinia tellus vel turpis vestibulum pharetra. Lestie, viverra mauris nec, semper turpis. Nunc accumsan augue ut ligula iaculis auctor.</p></div>

<div class="panelTab holder">   
<div class="text-block" > <h3>LOREM IPSUM</h3><p class="sub-title">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p> </div><div class="clearfix"></div></div>
<div class="animatedPanel"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ornare ornare lectus in pulvinar. Donec tempor odio sit amet phare- tra commodo. Suspendisse sem libero, tempor vitae egestas eu, sagittis sit amet metus. Sed congue tristique quam in gravida. Sed cursus, lectus vel rhoncus bibendum, erat ante mattis mauris, ac pharetra erat mauris nec turpis. Sed tincidunt aliquam est eget rhoncus. Proin eget metus ex. Sed sit amet eros feugiat, dignissim purus eget, rhoncus augue. Vestibulum lacinia tellus vel turpis vestibulum pharetra. Lestie, viverra mauris nec, semper turpis. Nunc accumsan augue ut ligula iaculis auctor.</p></div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('.animatedPanel').hide();
$('.panelTab').click(function() {
$('.panelTab').removeClass('active');
$(this).toggleClass('active');
var panel = $(this).next()
$('.animatedPanel').not(panel).slideUp();
panel.slideToggle({
    direction: "up"
}, 100);
$('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
}, 200);   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rmLo2n07/

Answer (score 0):

try changing the style of the hidden element 
position:absolute, display: block, visibility:hidden
then calculate it height and restore its old style

Comment: Thank you, actually that didn't quite work. What actually is happening is that the distance between the element and the top of the page is changing when you click and any divs above the element are collapsed. So I need to find a way to calculate the height of the page above the element after the collapse occurs.